# Block leak with __block variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, objective-c-blocks, weak-references

I have a big memory leak that I have pinpointed to happen in/on `requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:` method. If I understand it right it happens with the `img` variable. If I make it `__block __weak` the image is nil already after I assign it `(img = [UIImage...])`. Am I being silly somewhere? Or how would I avoid this memory leak?

```
- (UIImage*) getRightlySizedImgFromAsset:(PHAsset*)asset {

    __block UIImage *img;


    PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions *coptions = [PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions new];
    coptions.canHandleAdjustmentData = ^BOOL(PHAdjustmentData *adjustmentData) { return NO; };

    //semaphore used so the block runs synchronously and I can return img from this method at the end
    dispatch_semaphore_t sem = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    [asset requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:coptions completionHandler:^(PHContentEditingInput *contentEditingInput, NSDictionary *info) {
        NSURL* url = [contentEditingInput fullSizeImageURL];
        int orientation = [contentEditingInput fullSizeImageOrientation];

        CIImage* inputImage = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:url options:nil];
        inputImage = [inputImage imageByApplyingOrientation:orientation];
        CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

        img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[context createCGImage:inputImage fromRect:inputImage.extent]];

        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem);
    }];
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);


    if (needToDoSomethingWithImg){
        [self doSomethingWithImage:img];
    }


    return img;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the leak, but the use of semaphores to make an asynchronous function behave synchronously is almost always a bad idea. They made it asynchronous for a reason. Use asynchronous patterns (e.g. supply your own completion handler) rather than trying to return the image directly.

Comment: I agree with Rob. Using semaphores to make an async call synchronous is absurd. You end up blocking your UI, which is a very bad idea. If there is a network problem you can lock up the UI for up to 2 minutes, which is a really bad user experience. You need to rethink your design.

Comment: I'm not too experienced of a programmer and at this moment can't image a non messy way to do this in my case. I have a large range of tasks that need to happen in right order, all happening on bg queue, and continuing them from within this method seems very illogical to the overall task.. But yeah, maybe I am just unaware of a certain pattern..

Comment: If you really want debug the leak, you'll need to figure out what's going on in `[self doSomethingWithImage:]`. This method is only part of the picture, your `img` object goes elsewhere where it could be getting unnecessarily retained.

Comment: I wrote in the same comment - "all happening on bg queue", where bg = background ) SO is a great resource, but too often I have seen people assuming no one knows this thing about blocking the UI thread.. If I know of a semaphore, surely I should know better than to freeze my UI. Thanks for your answer and suggestion below though!

Comment: Sorry, no offense intended. It's just a horrible pattern and you admitted to being less experienced, so I assumed the worst. When you get around to it, check out asynchronous/concurrent `NSOperation` subclasses, which are elegant solution to this problem. Even dispatch groups are better than semaphores.

Comment: No worries, will check those out. If only I had the time to learn it all! But yeah the semaphore might just be the lesser evil in my case - the image is chosen, fetched (ALAsset for ios7, PHAsset for ios8), resized, processed, uploaded to s3 via Bolts, error handled etc etc etc and repeated for an image batch that changes on the fly - so to keep me sane and the code more or less clear - I kept it serial with a dispatch async on a background queue. Will see if I can improve it with NSOperation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run this code through the static analyzer (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> or choose "Analyze" from the "Product" menu) and it will point out that `createCGImage` is creating a `CGImageRef` that you're never releasing.

You might want to do something like:

```
CGImageRef imageRef = [context createCGImage:inputImage fromRect:inputImage.extent];
img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CFRelease(imageRef);
```

---

By the way, you should not do this synchronously. You should do something like:

```
- (void) getRightlySizedImgFromAsset:(PHAsset*)asset completionHandler:(void (^)(UIImage *))completionHandler {

    PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions *coptions = [PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions new];
    coptions.canHandleAdjustmentData = ^BOOL(PHAdjustmentData *adjustmentData) { return NO; };

    [asset requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:coptions completionHandler:^(PHContentEditingInput *contentEditingInput, NSDictionary *info) {
        NSURL* url = [contentEditingInput fullSizeImageURL];
        int orientation = [contentEditingInput fullSizeImageOrientation];

        CIImage* inputImage = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:url options:nil];
        inputImage = [inputImage imageByApplyingOrientation:orientation];
        CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

        CGImageRef imageRef = [context createCGImage:inputImage fromRect:inputImage.extent];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
        CFRelease(imageRef);

        // if this stuff needs to happen on main thread, then dispatch it to the main thread

        if (needtodosomethingwithit)
            [self doSomethingWithImage:image];

        if (completionHandler) {
            completionHandler(image);
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a tonne! Tested - the leak is gone. I ran the analyzer through, but the project is so big and messy (and I was suspecting the leak elsewhere when I ran it) that I managed to miss this one!

Answer (score 1):

Rob is right on the money. And images can be big, so that's why you have a big leak. The rule of thumb with Core Foundation objects is the "create rule." Search in Xcode on "Create Rule" and read the article. The gist of it is this:

> Core Foundation functions have names that indicate when you own a
>   returned object:
>
> Object-creation functions that have “Create” embedded in the name;
>
> Object-duplication functions that have “Copy” embedded in the name. If
>   you own an object, it is your responsibility to relinquish ownership
>   (using CFRelease) when you have finished with it.